# How to get repository url and plugin id from marketplace for Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I am provisioning Eclipse and Eclipse plugins to an Ubuntu Virtual Machine using vagrant and chef. All plugins need to be installed using equinox.p2. Here is an example of installing Buildship plugin:

eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/1.0 -installIUs org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group

In many cases a plugin only provides a marketplace Install button and no update site URL and no details on plugin id.

How can I get the update site URL and plugin id for such a plugin?

Answer (score 9):

This information is hidden unless you own the entry on the marketplace. However you can obtain it using the marketplace API. For instance getting the details on the OS X Eclipse Launcher, by issuing `curl http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/364668/api/p` on the command line and you'll get all the details in the form of XML. The update site URL is in *updateurl*, and the feature(s) are listed in *ius*. Replace the number with the identifier of the entry in the marketplace. You can find it by looking at the URL assigned to the **Install** link button.

Comment: Thanks so much for thing. Just a side note for people who may not know, you can copy and paste that url into your browser for the XML to get the information you may need.

Comment: To find out what should come after `-installIU`, I had to install manually once, then read the feature names from within Eclipse. (Installing [JBoss Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/1617241/api/p), feature groups `org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group` and `org.jboss.tools.usage.feature.feature.group`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's  [Returning a Specific Listing](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Marketplace/REST#Returning_a_Specific_Listing) section from the Marketpalce REST API documentation.

> There are two methods of returning a specific listing.
>
> [http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/[title]/api/p](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/%5Btitle%5D/api/p)
>
> [...]
>
> Calls to either URL will return a listing of contents of a node.

`[title]` is the identifier of a Marketplace plugin URL like in `filesync` in https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync. Fetch it and extract the two XPaths, `//node/updateurl` and `//node/ius/iu`, e.g. with Python (via [pyfil](https://pypi.org/project/pyfil/)).

```
$ wget -qO- http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync/api/p \
  | pyfil 'stdin.read()' \
    '__import__("xml.etree.ElementTree").etree.ElementTree.fromstring(x)' \
    '(x.find("node/updateurl").text,x.find("node/ius/iu").text)'
[
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iloveeclipse/plugins/latest/",
  "FileSync"
]
```