# Eclipse Marketplace plug-ins silent install

Tags: eclipse

I’m trying to establish a Ubuntu dev workstation in a VM that will serve as the base VM image for our team.  There are several Eclipse plugin we use for our development, I would like to script their install, and I would like to install from Marketplace.  Is that something achievable on Ubuntu? How would I lookup and reference the plugin, and then how would I initiate the install?  Or should I consider a different approach entirely?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[torkildr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955255/how-to-get-repository-url-and-plugin-id-from-marketplace-for-eclipse-plugin) has described a way to retrieve the repository URL and feature name from the Marketplace API.

Given a Marketplace install URL (`https://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install={ID}`), construct the API URL as `https://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/{ID}/api/p`. Retrieve the XML file from that URL and look for the repository URL in the `updateURL` tag, and the available features in the `ius` tag. You'll need to append `.feature.group` to each IU feature listed, so the final command to install one of the listed features is:

```
./eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository {repository URL} -installIU {iu}.feature.group
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine the Update Site and feature names from an existing install (the **About** dialog's **Installation Details** will show you the Feature IDs), you can drive the process headlessly via the [P2 Director](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html). For example, to tell it to install the MarketPlace Client itself:

```
./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen -installIU org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group -nosplash
```

As far as I can tell, the MarketPlace Client does not contribute an extension to `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications`, so you can't call it from the command line.